# Cannot access magento admin panel from edge browser

Tags: magento2, admin

I have installed wamp server 3.0.6 64 bit & Magento 2.1
 server on windows 10.

When I try to access magento admin panel from edge browser it does open the admin page i also see following URL 
http://localhost/magento/admin_ujwal/admin/index/index/key/8befcc252419fbc51aa80295b3b5ef2128b2dc762e9b226d0599e61774564477/

and wegpage displays "we cant reach the page"

how ever same is accessible from chrome. why i cant access my magento admin panel from MS edge browser

Comment: clear browser cookie and check again